# how to customize rails activerecord validation error message to show attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

When a user tries to create a record with a name that already exists, I want to show an error message like:

`name "some name" has already been taken`

I have been trying to do:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :message => "#{name} has already been taken"
```

but this outputs the table name instead of the value of the name attribute

Answer (score 46, accepted):

2 things:

1. The validation messages use the [Rails I18n style interpolation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation), which is `%{value}`
2. The key is `value` rather than `name`, because in the context of internationalization, you don't really care about the rest of the model.

So your code should be:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :message => '%{value} has already been taken'
```

Comment: Nice! Definitely cleaner than my answer.

Comment: It may be useful to know that %{attribute} is also available for use.

Answer (score 25):

It looks like you can pass a `Proc` to the message. When you do this, you get two parameters:

1. A symbol along the lines of `:activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.name.taken`
2. A hash that looks something like `{:model=>"User", :attribute=>"Name", :value=>"My Name"}

So if you allow for two parameters on a proc, you can use the `attributes[:value]` item to get the name that was used:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, 
                        :message => Proc.new { |error, attributes| 
                          "#{attributes[:value]} has already been taken." 
                        }
```

Answer (score 3):

What version of Rails do you use?

If Rails **3.** then as i understand you should use `:message => '%{value} has already been taken'`. I am not sure about Rails **2.3.** - but in any case you can create your own custom validation that performs what you need.

Comment: for this application, i am using rails 2.3.4