# Rails custom validation message with helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to give a custom validation message to a uniqueness validation. However, for the error message I need slightly complicated behavior, so I'm putting this logic in a private method (`error_message_for_email_uniqueness`).

Here's the code I'm using

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, message: error_message_for_email_uniqueness
```

Here's the error I'm getting

```
/Users/dylandrop/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/attr_encrypted-1.2.0/lib/attr_encrypted.rb:229:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `error_message_for_email_uniqueness' for #<Class:0x00000103684198> (NameError)
```

I've tried using `message: lambda { error_message_for_email_uniqueness }`, which also doesn't work. Also, I've tried wrapping it in a Proc instead of a lambda, which doesn't get me anywhere.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you define error_message_for_email_uniqueness as a class method?

I did a quick test, and this works fine:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, message: Proc.new { error_message_for_email_uniqueness }

def self.error_message_for_email_uniqueness
  # logic to generate message goes here
end
```

Comment: Oh I hadn't tried with the lambda and the class method. Assumed it would be instance. Do you need those params for the lambda?

Comment: Tried without the params, it seems to work, I edited my answer.  You can also reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073303/how-to-customize-rails-activerecord-validation-error-message-to-show-attribute-v

Comment: Also, would you happen to know how/if I could pass the record to `error_message_for_email_uniqueness`? I know you can pass the error and attributes, but I need to check if the record being saved is new or not....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create messages dynamically based on model attributes or something, you should create custom validator, because message is expected to be string.

Comment: problem is I don't really want to recreate `validates_uniqueness_of`