# Rails errors.add override :invalid without creating a language file entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, symbols

I am working to solve my problem to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27735880/689554) and I think I am close to a solution, but I have run into another problem. I am trying to copy code I found in the rails source and modify it to fit my needs:

I have created the following custom validator:

```
class ExistingTwoValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless Group.where(:code => value).any?
     record.errors.add(attribute, :invalid, options.merge(:value => value))
     record.errors.add(attribute, "custom error", options.merge(:value => value))
     record.errors.add(attribute, :madeup, options.merge(:value => value))
    end
  end
end
```

If I provide a custom error message in my model:

```
validates :group_code, existing_two: { message: "My custom message %{value} is not okay."}
```

For invalid input (e.g., "www") I get the following errors:

- Group code My custom message www is not okay.
- Group code custom error
- Group code My custom message www is not okay.

If I do not provide a custom error message:

```
validates :group_code, existing_two: true
```

For invalid input (e.g., "www") I get the following errors:

- Group code is invalid
- Group code custom error
- Group code translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.models.*XX*.attributes.group_code.madeup

---

The first `record.errors.add(attribute, :invalid, ...` will allow me to override the default message in :invalid, but if I provide literal string as the second argument (e.g. `record.errors.add(attribute, "custom error"`, it will not let me override the message.

I want to understand the logic that says if it's a symbol it can be replaced but if its a string ignore the message passed in the options. Also, is there any way to provide the custom message without using a symbol or is there a way to define the symbol without adding it to a language file somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

### Reviewing the following snippets from active model errors.

---

```
# File activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb, Line 299
def add(attribute, message = :invalid, options = {})
  message = normalize_message(attribute, message, options)
  if exception = options[:strict]
    exception = ActiveModel::StrictValidationFailed if exception == true
    raise exception, full_message(attribute, message)
  end

  self[attribute] << message
end
```

---

```
#File activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb, line 438
def normalize_message(attribute, message, options)
  case message
  when Symbol
    generate_message(attribute, message, options.except(*CALLBACKS_OPTIONS))
  when Proc
    message.call
  else
    message
  end
end
```

---

```
# File activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb, line 412
def generate_message(attribute, type = :invalid, options = {})
  type = options.delete(:message) if options[:message].is_a?(Symbol)

  if @base.class.respond_to?(:i18n_scope)
    defaults = @base.class.lookup_ancestors.map do |klass|
      [ :"#{@base.class.i18n_scope}.errors.models.#{klass.model_name.i18n_key}.attributes.#{attribute}.#{type}",
        :"#{@base.class.i18n_scope}.errors.models.#{klass.model_name.i18n_key}.#{type}" ]
    end
  else
    defaults = []
  end

  defaults << options.delete(:message)
  defaults << :"#{@base.class.i18n_scope}.errors.messages.#{type}" if @base.class.respond_to?(:i18n_scope)
  defaults << :"errors.attributes.#{attribute}.#{type}"
  defaults << :"errors.messages.#{type}"

  defaults.compact!
  defaults.flatten!

  key = defaults.shift
  value = (attribute != :base ? @base.send(:read_attribute_for_validation, attribute) : nil)

  options = {
    default: defaults,
    model: @base.model_name.human,
    attribute: @base.class.human_attribute_name(attribute),
    value: value
  }.merge!(options)

  I18n.translate(key, options)
end
```

---

You're calling *errors.add*, which calls the private method *normalize_message*, the *normalise_message* method takes the message and if it's a Symbol calls *generate_message*. In the *generate_message* method it ends up falling back to the default message because it is unable to find the translation in *activemodel.errors.models.MODEL.attributes.ATTRIBUTE.MESSAGE* or *activemodel.errors.models.MODEL.MESSAGE*

I strongly suggest you read the source code link I've provided as it is well documented and is very in depth.

[Active Model Errors](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb)

Comment: Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Here, tried to improve answer. But you did not explain your desired result so I'm unsure how else I can answer. @paritosh solution should work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This is how can you can do it simply

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :group_code, presence: true
  validate do |example|
    unless Group.where(:code => example.group_code).any?
      example.errors.add(:base, "The code you have entered #{example.group_code} is not a valid code, please check with your teacher or group")
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, you can also extract the the above logic and put it into custom validator.

Note that , i am passing `:base` not `attribute`.

Basically, the interpolation is done with i18n gem.

You can see [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb#L442)