# How to pass the value of column to the custom error message of validates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have a model with 2 column, `name` and `answer`

How can I pass the value of `name` to the custom error message of validates of a model.

*sample code:*

```
#app/models/sample_model.rb
Class SampleModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :answer, 
                :presence => {:message => "Error name: #{self.name}"}
end
```

Instead of the value of column `name`, it shows the name of the model which is **SampleModel**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to customize rails activerecord validation error message to show attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073303/how-to-customize-rails-activerecord-validation-error-message-to-show-attribute-v)

Comment: NO, that one is getting the value inserted to that validated field. What I need is getting the value from the other field. I validate the presence of the `answer` and I want to display the value of `name` to the error message. That name field is auto populated by me

Answer (score 2):

To have access to the value of an attribute (column) being validated, you need to use the `ActiveModel::Validations` class. That class has a `validates_each` method that you can use to access the values of a record being validated.

```
#app/models/sample_model.rb
class SampleModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :sample_attribute

  validates_each :sample_attribute allow_blank: true do |record, attr, value|
      record.errors.add :base, 'Error name: #{value}' if value.nil?
  end
end
```

In `record.errors.add` is where you can customize your message. It takes three parameters `attribute`, `message`, and `options`. In the above, I put `:base` for the attribute basically to customize further you custom message.

See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_each) for more info on the validates_each method and [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add) for the 'add' method in the Active Model Errors class. Also [this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) on the Rails Guide will help.